# Finding the domain of the derivative of a natural log function.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

Given the function $f(x)=ln(x^2-14x)$, find the derivative and the domain of f.

I found the derivative to be $\frac{2(x-7)}{x(x-14)}$ which was correct. I then tried to find the domain by finding where the denominator was equal to zero, which is at x=0 and x=14. I thought that the domain would be (-infinity, 0), (0, 14), (14, infinity), but the correct domain is without the (0, 14). I don't understand why (0, 14) is not in the domain, can somebody help explain it to me?

Comment: It is because $x^2-14x<0$  on $(0,14)$, so $f(x)$ isn't defined.

Comment: Additional comment: $\ln u$ is not defined when $u \leq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The question asks for the domain of *$f$*, not $f'$, so you must decide where
$$
f(x)=\ln(x^2-14x)
$$
makes sense
or where 
$$
x^2-14x>0\Rightarrow x<0\;\text{or}\;x>14
$$